# best way to have unlimited object queue between two process in c++

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, shared-memory

i have two processes so process one generate some container object and send it to process two.
what is best way to have object queue between two process .i prefer boost library,
but as i know with shared memory we cant have unlimited memory space in share.

Comment: *Nothing* is unlimited. You *have* to define an upper bound, very large if you want, but fixed.

Comment: `#include <perpetual-motion-machine>`

Comment: Using an IPC mechanism depends on number of criteria: 1. If the processes are related. 3. If you can bear the Synchronization overhead 2. The performance you expect from the mechanism and so on, No IPC mechanism is *unlimited* You have to chose the one best suited to your requirement.

Comment: check the mit/intel project cilk++  , its uses a work stealing scheduler for assigning threads it may be of use or perhaps even openMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, e.g., shared memory, pipes or sockets or TCP for normal sized queues between processes. If you really need to funnel huge amount of data then you might want to also consider using files, sending only, e.g., file names through your queue.

Nevertheless, there is **always** some kind of a limit there.